# Calculate Current Inventory from Three Arrays of Values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Sudipta's suggestion worked. Now I am having difficulty getting the final script to display online. The script displays properly in phpMyAdmin SQL editor.

```
$sql = "CREATE  TABLE Inv_Physical_Count
        SELECT  SUM(qty) as qty, excel_part_num, part_id, part_desc, order_form_seq
        FROM    Inventory, Inventory_Items, Parts
        WHERE   Inventory.id = Inventory_Items.inventory_id
        AND     Inventory_Items.part_id = Parts.id
        AND     Inventory.date = '2017-01-05'
        AND     Inventory.inv_type_id = '2'
        GROUP BY part_id
        ORDER BY part_id";

        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array());

$sql = "CREATE  TABLE Inv_Restock
        SELECT  SUM(qty) as qty, excel_part_num, part_id, part_desc, order_form_seq
        FROM    Inventory, Inventory_Items, Parts
        WHERE   Inventory.id = Inventory_Items.inventory_id
        AND     Inventory_Items.part_id = Parts.id
        AND     Inventory.date >=  '2017-01-05'
        AND     Inventory.date <  '2017-07-04'
        AND     Inventory.inv_type_id = '1'
        GROUP BY part_id
        ORDER BY part_id";

        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array());

$sql = "CREATE  TABLE Inv_Orders
        SELECT  SUM(qty) as qty, excel_part_num, part_id, part_desc, order_form_seq
        FROM    Orders, Order_Items, Parts
        WHERE   Orders.id = Order_Items.orders_id
        AND     Order_Items.part_id = Parts.id
        AND     Orders.date_order >= '2017-01-05'
        AND     Orders.date_order < '2017-07-04'
        GROUP BY part_id
        ORDER BY part_id";

        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array());
```

The following SQL script works in SQL Editor in phpMyAdmin. However, in PHP I cannot get this script to display real content. It is all blank.

```
$sql = "SELECT  a.qty + b.qty - c.qty as 'QTY', a.excel_part_num as 'Part Num', a.part_desc as 'Description'
        FROM    Inv_Physical_Count a,
                Inv_Restock b,
                Inv_Orders c
        WHERE   a.part_id = b.part_id
        AND     a.part_id = c.part_id
        ORDER BY a.order_form_seq";

        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array());

        while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
            echo    '<tr>';
            echo    '<td>' . $row['qty'] . '</td>';
            echo    '<td>' . $row['excel_part_num'] . '</td>';
            echo    '<td>' . $row['part_desc'] . '</td>';               
        }
```

Comment: Note that, even where there's a relational dependency, it's generally best to GROUP BY the same thing that you SELECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not combine all your queries as per below. It will work, if you have the same part_id, if its not same, maybe you can join the tables with `part_num` and not `part_id`

```
SELECT SUM(a.qty + b.qty - c.qty), part_num
FROM Phys_Count a
LEFT JOIN Items_Received b
ON  a.part_id = b.part_id
JOIN items_shipped c
ON  a.part_id = c.part_id
WHERE ...
GROUP BY part_num
ORDER BY part_id
```

Comment: Hello Sudipta - This is an intriguing idea. Now the devil is in the details. I have posted my actual script because I think it may be helpful. I am getting syntax errors. See updated code above

Comment: @Bricked - are you getting errors in your sql or your php code ? and what exact error message do you receive ?

Comment: SQL error. I always test in SQL first to isolate and perfect. Then I struggle through php implementation ;-)  Here is my error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN FROM Inventory, Inventory_Items b, Parts WHERE Invento' at line 7

Comment: @Bricked - Quite a bit is wrong with the SQL :) 
is this what you want to do ? `sum quantity for XYZ part_num, where inv_type_id = 2 ` +(plus) `sum the quantity for XYZ where inv_type_id = 1` -(minus) `sum of quantity for party XYZ which is available in order_items` ?

Comment: @ Sudipta - I am using the same table to store different values based on inv_type_id. inv_type_id = 1 (items received)
inv_type_id = 2 (physical inventory)
Then I am using Orders_Items for items shipped. The scripts work great separately, but merging them is challenging